Flux.delayElements function from Reactor not working as expected
testing the delayElements method from Reactor with this test:
@Test
void testDelayElementsOnFlux() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.range(1,5).log().delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(200)).subscribe(System.out::println);
    Thread.sleep(120000);
}

I get the next logs:
22:05:15.938 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework
22:05:16.052 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] 
FluxRange.RangeSubscription)
22:05:16.061 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | request(32)
22:05:16.062 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(1)
22:05:16.071 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(2)
22:05:16.072 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(3)
22:05:16.072 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(4)
22:05:16.072 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(5)
22:05:16.072 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onComplete()
1
2
3
4
5

According to the documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-, it says "Delay each of this Flux elements (Subscriber.onNext(T) signals) by a given Duration" .

So, why the onNext methods dont have a delay of 200 miliseconds between them and are emitted 5 elements in batching way if I explicitly used "delayElements" method?.
As it can be seen in the log, after the onComplete() calling, its logged 1 to 5 in the logs. Its like the delay is applied after the emission of the five elements. Why is this?

Thanks.

Operator order matter. You ask to log before delaying, so the logged onNext signals are not delayed. After that, you add a delay, so after range items are emitted and logged, they are delayed, and the subscription receive that result and print delayed items to the console.
